# TypeError: process.versions.node is undefined

Tags: node.js, next.js, auth0, supabase

I have a Next.js dynamic route which is fetching 2 things: the context.query and a row from Supabase. This is the code for the `getServerSideProps` function of the route `[username].js` The page uses Auth0 for authentication, therefore I have used `withPageAuthRequired` in `getServerSideProps`

```js
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired({
  async getServerSideProps(context) {
    // const session = getSession(context.req, context.res);
    const username = context.query.username;
    console.log(username);
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("Users")
      .select()
      .eq("username", username);

    if (error || data.length == 0) {
      console.log(data);
      return {
        notFound: true,
      };
    }
    console.log(data);
    return {
      props: data[0],
    };
  },
});
```

The fact that I did run some directory-level and global-level npm updates, but I don't know why the node version is coming up as undefined when the code is running on the server-side.

Here is the full error message if that helps:

```
Call Stack
<unknown>
node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/shake256.js (3:23)
./node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/shake256.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (958:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/index.js (5:25)
./node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/index.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (948:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js (9:26)
./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (968:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js (5:26)
./node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (1208:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/openid-client/lib/index.js (1:23)
./node_modules/openid-client/lib/index.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (1198:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/auth0-session/transient-store.js (4:30)
./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/auth0-session/transient-store.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (128:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/auth0-session/index.js (21:32)
./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/auth0-session/index.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (84:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/index.js (6:30)
./node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/index.js
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (315:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
webpack-internal:///./src/pages/user/[username].jsx (22:96)
./src/pages/user/[username].jsx
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/pages/user/%5Busername%5D.js (768:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (691:31)
__webpack_require__
file:/Users/vidit/GitHubProjects/squawk-components/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (346:21)
<unknown>
node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=%2FUsers%2Fvidit%2FGitHubProjects%2Fsquawk-components%2Fsrc%2Fpages%2Fuser%2F%5Busername%5D.jsx&page=%2Fuser%2F%5Busername%5D! (5:15)
execute
node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js (211:50)
```

I updated all the installed packages using npm update --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: same here, I haven't figured out a workaround yet, apart from https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7230